# can't get elements to match a certain data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

When I try to get with elements with the same data-id it doesn't give the desired results.

```
    $('.edit_reply').live("click", function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $links = $("td[id*="+id+"]");
    alert($links.length);
    }


<tr data-id="{{ replyId }}">

         <td class="span3">
             <i class="icon-trash  delete_reply" data-id="{{ replyId }}"/>
             <i class="icon-edit  edit_reply"  data-id="{{ replyId }}"/>
         </td>
         <td  data-id="{{ replyId }}">

            {{{ reply }}}

        </td>
```

EDIT:
data-id is something like this.

id = e03747d1-3aa0-4224-b8b0-aa6afe713e74

First I thought as it might cz this string is big.
So I set this as an id="e03747d1-3aa0-4224-b8b0-aa6afe713e74"
and checked

```
    $links = $("td[id*='e03747d1-3aa0-4224-b8b0-aa6afe713e74']");
```

and it worked.

Using data('id') gives same results.

```
   var id = $(this).data('id');
```

why does this happen. Any thoughts?

Comment: what is the value of `id` and can you give a sample of value that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** to get the value of `data-*` attribute:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Also note that `live()` is deprecated since version `1.7` and removed in version `1.9`, you should use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead.

Comment: if the attribute is present how does it make a difference... until there is a programatic change to the value using the data api

Answer (score 0):

```
 var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $links = $("td[id*='"+id+"']"); //apply '"+id +"'
```

you can also do by **[data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Comment: if the attribute is present how does it make a difference... until there is a programatic change to the value using the data api